# Why is question not updated with my service call in react

Tags: reactjs

I tested out the fetch and it returns the correct data I need it to but I get an empty array for questions in my uuid

Here is my code

```
function App() {
  const [questions, setQuestions] = useState<QuestionHeader[]>([]);
  const [surveyQuestions, setSurvey] = useState<QuestionHeader[]>([]);
  const columnsFromBackend = {
    [uuid()]: {
      name: "Requested",
      items: questions
    },
    [uuid()]: {
      name: "To do",
      items: []
    },
  };
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState(columnsFromBackend);
  useEffect(() =>  {
    const requestOptions = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
    };
    fetch(`url`, requestOptions)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(e => {
      setQuestions(e)
    });
  },[])
```

Comment: Do you receive a valid response on fetch? Check the data that you receive before calling `setQuestions`

Comment: are you sure that your UUID doesn't change? Can you check if the question array is non-empty?